# Hibernate: Case insensitive search does not work for special characters

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hql, case-insensitive

I have a search HQL query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Recipe.findByTitle", query = "SELECT r.title FROM Recipe r WHERE UPPER(r.title) LIKE :titlePart")
```

In database I have the following value:`Heiße Suppe`.
Due to case insensitive search, I need to set the input string to uppercase in Java too. I try to search for this entry, by passing the characters `eiße`:

```
language = "de";
characters = "eiße";
queryTitle.setParameter("titlePart", "%" + characters.toUpperCase(new Locale(language)) + "%");
```

It is expected, that the sharp s ('ß') will be transformed to SS by Java because of the German locale. This works (although it even works with Locale.ENGLISH, but that's another question).. Nevertheless, the problem is that HQL's `UPPER` does not transform the sharp s 'ß' to SS, that's why it does not return any result. I'm not sure what hibernate is doing in UPPER with special characters, but it is not the same Java is doing. (It works only for non-special characters).
For this one case, a solution would be to set both to lower case, but I doubt that this works for all languages in the world with special characters, or is the solution to always use toLowerCase, for any language?

[UPDATE]
I'm still not sure if this works for all languages, but I made some tests with greek values. I inserted the greek capital letters alpha to gamma (`ΑΒΓΔ`) into the database but then I search for small letters alpha to gamma (`αβγδ`), and the result was found. Maybe it is the common way to lower the values, because the database lowers the values properly. I just wonder if this works for any language.

Comment: What collation are you using in the table?  The upper/lower case behavior in sql depends on collation.

Comment: @MikhailChibel The collation is always en_US.UTF-8. How does this affect the search?

Comment: I believe this is not the problem with hql,  but rather sql itself.  If your character not in the colllation table the sql may not know how to convert the character to lower or uppercase. This is why it works for Greek symbols and for german.  Anyway, you better to try execute query directly in sql, at least you will know that it is or it isn't hql who creates problems.

Comment: @MikhailChibel I think that ursa's solution is quite good. I will do the conversion only in the queries, so it probably doesn't matter if it converts it to wrong characters since there are no two different types of conversion now (Before: Java conversion and database conversion, Now: database conversion only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use either ILIKE:

```
query = "SELECT r.title FROM Recipe r WHERE r.title ILIKE ('%' || :titlePart || '%')"
```

or case transformation for both parts in Hibernate:

```
query = "SELECT r.title FROM Recipe r WHERE UPPER(r.title) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:titlePart) || '%')"
```

where

```
queryTitle.setParameter("titlePart", characters);
```

I do not recommend to transform case in Java - it will lead to hard for investigation errors...

Comment: `ILIKE` does not seem to work in HQL, but the second attempt works.

Comment: Additional information: But it does not seem to work with `WHERE LOWER(somevalue) IN (LOWER(:list))

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(character varying, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: IN clause requires a custom stored function - to change the case for the list of values (apply UPPER or LOWER to all items in the list).

Comment: Yes, but I need to do that in Java code, because I can't do it in HQL, or are there any possibilities to do so?

Comment: spreading case convertion logic between Java and DB is error prone approach. of cause there are possibilities, read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/) or [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-load) examples.